# Find the smallest positive number not in list

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python like this:

```
myList = [1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]
```

How can I easily find the first unused value? (in this case '4')

Comment: should `[2,3,4,6]` return 1? or should it return 5?

Comment: It should return 1.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I came up with several different ways:

### Iterate the first number not in set

I didn't want to get the shortest code (which might be the set-difference trickery) but something that could have a good running time.

This might be one of the best proposed here, my tests show that it might be substantially faster - especially if the hole is in the beginning - than the set-difference approach:

```
from itertools import count, filterfalse # ifilterfalse on py2

A = [1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]
print(next(filterfalse(set(A).__contains__, count(1))))
```

The array is turned into a `set`, whose `__contains__(x)` method corresponds to `x in A`. `count(1)` creates a counter that starts counting from 1 to infinity. Now, `filterfalse` consumes the numbers from the counter, until a number is found that is not in the set; when the first number is found that is not in the set it is yielded by `next()`

Timing for `len(a) = 100000`, randomized and the sought-after number is `8`:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: next(filterfalse(set(a).__contains__, count(1))), number=100)
0.9200698399945395
>>> timeit(lambda: min(set(range(1, len(a) + 2)) - set(a)), number=100)
3.1420603669976117
```

Timing for `len(a) = 100000`, ordered and the first free is `100001`

```
>>> timeit(lambda: next(filterfalse(set(a).__contains__, count(1))), number=100)
1.520096342996112
>>> timeit(lambda: min(set(range(1, len(a) + 2)) - set(a)), number=100)
1.987783643999137
```

(note that this is Python 3 and `range` is the py2 `xrange`)

### Use heapq

The asymptotically good answer: `heapq` with `enumerate`

```
from heapq import heapify, heappop

heap = list(A)
heapify(heap)

from heapq import heapify, heappop
from functools import partial

# A = [1,2,3] also works
A = [1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]

end = 2 ** 61      # these are different and neither of them can be the 
sentinel = 2 ** 62 # first gap (unless you have 2^64 bytes of memory).

heap = list(A)
heap.append(end)
heapify(heap)

print(next(n for n, v in enumerate(
     iter(partial(heappop, heap), sentinel), 1) if n != v))
```

Now, the one above could be the preferred solution if written in C, but `heapq` is written in Python and most probably slower than many other alternatives that mainly use C code.

### Just sort and enumerate to find the first not matching

Or the simple answer with good constants for O(n lg n)

```
next(i for i, e in enumerate(sorted(A) + [ None ], 1) if i != e)
```

This might be fastest of all **if** the list is almost sorted because of how the Python Timsort works, but for randomized the set-difference and iterating the first not in set are faster.

The `+ [ None ]` is necessary for the edge cases of there being no gaps (e.g. `[1,2,3]`).

Comment: This performs slower than looping through positive integers. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74332660/3357935

Answer (score 8):

This makes use of the property of sets

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,5,7,8,12,14]
>>> m = range(1,len(l))
>>> min(set(m)-set(l))
4
```

Comment: Use `min` to keep it linear in terms of complexity.

Comment: This is actually so smart! But I would do `min(set(range(max(l) + 2)) - set(l))` instead.

Comment: This seems less efficient than just doing a for loop

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you to use a generator and use enumerate to determine the missing element

```
>>> next(a for a, b in enumerate(myList, myList[0]) if a != b)
4
```

[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) maps the index with the element so your goal is to determine that element which differs from its index.
Note, I am also assuming that the elements may not start with a definite value, in this case which is `1`, and if it is so, you can simplify the expression further as

```
>>> next(a for a, b in enumerate(myList, 1) if a != b)
4
```

Comment: derp.  enumerate.  Why didn't I think of that?  +1

Comment: The list is not guaranteed to be sorted

Comment: In that case sort your list before processing.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know how efficient, but why not use an xrange as a mask and use set minus?

```
>>> myList = [1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]
>>> min(set(xrange(1, len(myList) + 1)) - set(myList))
4
```

You're only creating a set as big as `myList`, so it can't be that bad :)

This won't work for "full" lists:

```
>>> myList = range(1, 5)
>>> min(set(xrange(1, len(myList) + 1)) - set(myList))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

But the fix to return the next value is simple  (add one more to the masked set):

```
>>> min(set(xrange(1, len(myList) + 2)) - set(myList))
5
```

Comment: It is the shortest and the most beautiful :D though not fastest

Answer (score 6):

A for loop with the list will do it.

```
l = [1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]
for i in range(1, max(l)):
    if i not in  l: break
print(i) # result 4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools as it

next(i for i in it.count() if i not in mylist)
```

I like this because it reads very closely to what you're trying to do: "start counting, keep going until you reach a number that isn't in the list, then tell me that number". However, this is quadratic since testing `i not in mylist` is linear.

Solutions using enumerate are linear, but rely on the list being sorted and no value being repeated. Sorting first makes it O(n log n) overall, which is still better than quadratic. However, if you can assume the values are distinct, then you could put them into a set first:

```
myset = set(mylist)
next(i for i in it.count() if i not in myset)
```

Since set containment checks are roughly constant time, this will be linear overall.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this in a probably non pythonic way

```
def solution(A):
    # Const-ish to improve readability
    MIN = 1
    if not A: return MIN
    # Save re-computing MAX
    MAX = max(A)
    # Loop over all entries with minimum of 1 starting at 1
    for num in range(1, MAX):
        # going for greatest missing number return optimistically (minimum)
        # If order needs to switch, then use max as start and count backwards
        if num not in A: return num
    # In case the max is < 0 double wrap max with minimum return value
    return max(MIN, MAX+1)
```

I think it reads quite well

Answer (score 2):

Easy to read, easy to understand, gets the job done:

```
def solution(A):
    smallest = 1
    unique = set(A)
    for int in unique:
        if int == smallest:
            smallest += 1
    return smallest
```

Answer (score 1):

My effort, no itertools. Sets "current" to be the one less than the value you are expecting.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8]
current = list[0]-1
for i in list:
    if i != current+1:
        print current+1
        break
    current = i
```

Answer (score 1):

The naive way is to traverse the list which is an O(n) solution. However, since the list is sorted, you can use this feature to perform binary search (a modified version for it). Basically, you are looking for the last occurance of A[i] = i.

The pseudo algorithm will be something like:

```
binarysearch(A):
  start = 0
  end = len(A) - 1
  while(start <= end ):
    mid = (start + end) / 2
    if(A[mid] == mid):
      result = A[mid]
      start = mid + 1
    else: #A[mid] > mid since there is no way A[mid] is less than mid
      end = mid - 1
  return (result + 1)
```

This is an O(log n) solution. I assumed lists are one indexed. You can modify the indices accordingly

EDIT: if the list is not sorted, you can use the heapq python library and store the list in a min-heap and then pop the elements one by one

pseudo code

```
H = heapify(A) //Assuming A is the list
count = 1
for i in range(len(A)):
  if(H.pop() != count): return count
  count += 1
```

Comment: Nice idea, but the list is **NOT** guaranteed to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

sort + reduce to the rescue!

```
from functools  import reduce # python3
myList = [1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]
res = 1 + reduce(lambda x, y: x if y-x>1 else y, sorted(myList), 0)
print(res)
```

Unfortunatelly it won't stop after match is found and will iterate whole list.

Faster (but less fun) is to use for loop:

```
myList = [1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]
res = 0
for num in sorted(myList):
    if num - res > 1:
        break
    res = num
res = res + 1
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
for i in range(1,max(arr1)+2):
        if i not in arr1:
            print(i)
            break
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be just to loop through the sorted list and check if the index is equal the value and if not return the index as solution.
This would have complexity O(nlogn) because of the sorting:

```
for index,value in enumerate(sorted(myList)):
    if index is not value:
        print(index)
        break
```

Another option is to use python sets which are somewhat dictionaries without values, just keys. In dictionaries you can look for a key in constant time which make the whol solution look like the following, having only linear complexity O(n):

```
mySet = set(myList)
for i in range(len(mySet)):
    if i not in mySet:
        print(i)
        break
```

Edit:
If the solution should also deal with lists where no number is missing (e.g. `[0,1]`) and output the next following number and should also correctly consider 0, then a complete solution would be:

```
def find_smallest_positive_number_not_in_list(myList):
    mySet = set(myList)
    for i in range(1, max(mySet)+2):
        if i not in mySet:
            return i
```

Comment: Your first solution does not work. Consider the list `[0, 1]`.

Comment: it does, the solution to your list is None, as there is no positive number missing in the list. Read again the question, the task is not to find a positive number bigger than the greatest number available in the list. that would be a different task.

Comment: The question is to "find the smallest positive number not in list". `None` is not a positive number. See the other answers.

Comment: I meant the answer is nothing, or empty, or also NONE. 
You are right, if the answer is based only on the title of the question, then a number not included in the list must also be a possible answer. However, if you read the thread and the comments of the questioner, you can see that this is not part of the task.
But if you insist i can add this edge case to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Keep incrementing a counter in a loop until you find the first positive integer that's not in the list.

```
def getSmallestIntNotInList(number_list):
    """Returns the smallest positive integer that is not in a given list"""
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        if i not in number_list:
            return i    

print(getSmallestIntNotInList([1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]))
# 4
```

I found that this had the fastest performance compared to other answers on this post. I tested using `timeit` in Python 3.10.8. My performance results can be seen below:

```
import timeit

def findSmallestIntNotInList(number_list):
    # Infinite while-loop until first number is found
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        if i not in number_list:
            return i

t = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList([1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]))
print('Execution time:', t.timeit(100000), 'seconds')
# Execution time: 0.038100800011307 seconds
```

```
import timeit

def findSmallestIntNotInList(number_list):
    # Loop with a range to len(number_list)+1 
    for i in range (1, len(number_list)+1):
        if i not in number_list:
            return i

t = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList([1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]))
print('Execution time:', t.timeit(100000), 'seconds')
# Execution time: 0.05068870005197823 seconds
```

```
import timeit

def findSmallestIntNotInList(number_list):
    # Loop with a range to max(number_list) (by silgon)
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/49649558/3357935
    for i in range (1, max(number_list)):
        if i not in number_list:
            return i

t = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList([1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]))
print('Execution time:', t.timeit(100000), 'seconds')
# Execution time: 0.06317249999847263 seconds
```

```
import timeit
from itertools import count, filterfalse

def findSmallestIntNotInList(number_list):
    # iterate the first number not in set (by Antti Haapala -- Слава Україні)
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/28178803/3357935
    return(next(filterfalse(set(number_list).__contains__, count(1))))

t = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList([1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]))
print('Execution time:', t.timeit(100000), 'seconds')
# Execution time: 0.06515420007053763 seconds
```

```
import timeit

def findSmallestIntNotInList(number_list):
    # Use property of sets (by Bhargav Rao)
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/28176962/3357935
    m = range(1, len(number_list))
    return min(set(m)-set(number_list))

t = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList([1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]))
print('Execution time:', t.timeit(100000), 'seconds')
# Execution time: 0.08586219989228994 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that returns all those values is

```
free_values = set(range(1, max(L))) - set(L)
```

it does a full scan, but those loops are implemented in C and unless the list or its maximum value are huge this will be a win over more sophisticated algorithms performing the looping in Python.

Note that if this search is needed to implement "reuse" of IDs then keeping a free list around and maintaining it up-to-date (i.e. adding numbers to it when deleting entries and picking from it when reusing entries) is a often a good idea.

Comment: What if the list is `[1, 2, 100000000000]` -- that's a pretty small list that will perform really badly with this answer ;-)

Comment: @mgilson: true, fixed the note

Comment: I still don't think this will be a win over the `enumerate` solution.  This has 3 O(len(L)) steps and an O(max(L)) step in addition to a decent amount of intermediate storage.  Plus, if OP really only wants the first out of place element, then you need to sort free_values (Of course, if OP wants them _all_ then this becomes a bit more competitive to an analogous `enumerate` solution)  But anyway, without seeing timings, I'm skeptical that this will be a win even in the scenario where OP does need all "free values" (though you're welcome to prove me wrong :-)

Comment: @mgilson: creating a set from `range` and then performing a set intersection or performing a loop in Python... I'm indeed curious and not 100% sure the set solution is faster (bytecode interpreting is 100x slower than C, but there's hashing and stuff so may be you're right... I'll check). Note that the list is not guaranteed to be sorted, so enumerating is not enough...

Answer (score 0):

The following solution loops all numbers in between 1 and the length of the input list and breaks the loop whenever a number is not found inside it. Otherwise the result is the length of the list plus one.

```
listOfNumbers=[1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]
for i in range(1, len(listOfNumbers)+1):
   if not i in listOfNumbers: 
      nextNumber=i
      break
else:
   nextNumber=len(listOfNumbers)+1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why is the else statement needed? Wouldn't using the range of `len(listOfNumbers)+1` cover every possibility?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this the best approach. I have delt with the negatives (<=0) and duplicates (i +=2) after sorting, then now working in checking if the integer missing is within the array by while loop if not we increment the last integer in array to get the next one as the missing integer

```
def getSmallInt(A):

    A.sort()
    n = len(A)-1
    if A[0]<=0:
        return 1
    if A[n]<=0:
        return 1
    i=0
    while i <n:
        j = A[i]
        next = A[i+1]
        first_step = next- j
        if first_step==1:
            i+=1
        elif first_step==0:
            i+=2
        if first_step >1:
            print(j+1)
            return j+1
    print(A[n]+1)
    return A[n]+1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myList = [1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12]
    getSmallInt(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this question in a coding challenge yesterday and thought about this a bit.

Coding challenge: https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/

This answer times several solutions, but only for one example input list:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74332660/22656217

Timing the solutions utilizing the for loop and the set method for different lists reveals more about in which cases the set method outperforms the for loop method, namely long lists due to the complexity scaling. I added a third solution here, which removes numbers that were checked already from the list (at least the first instance of them) via the remove() built-in.

```
import timeit

def findSmallestIntNotInList(number_list):
    # Infinite while-loop until first number is found
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        if i not in number_list:
            return i

def findSmallestIntNotInList_remove(number_list):
    # Infinite while-loop until first number is found
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        if i not in number_list:
            return i
        else:
            number_list.remove(i)

def findSmallestIntNotInList_set(number_list):
    m = range(1, len(number_list)+2)
    return min(set(m)-set(number_list))

lists = [[1,14,2,5,3,7,8,12],list(range(100)),[1,100],list(range(10))+[100]]
for l in lists:
    t = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList(l))
    t2 = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList_remove(l))
    t3 = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList_set(l))
    print('Execution time for:', t.timeit(100000), 'seconds')
    print('Execution time rem:', t2.timeit(100000), 'seconds')
    print('Execution time set:', t3.timeit(100000), 'seconds')
    print('------------')
```

I have several questions about this now, because I submitted both the set method as well as the remove method as solutions, the set method scoring 100% and the remove method only 25%. However, as you can see from the code above the remove method outperforms the set method when timing it.

1. Can you think of a case, where the remove method performs badly?
2. Does the remove method score badly on a different performance metric not related to timing, like cache access or something?
3. Why does the coding challenge assign a lower score to the remove method?

Output of the code on my system:

```
Execution time for: 0.033844683 seconds
Execution time rem: 0.016967110999999993 seconds
Execution time set: 0.08823136799999999 seconds
------------
Execution time for: 3.6741308530000003 seconds
Execution time rem: 0.013037643000000099 seconds
Execution time set: 0.06054173700000032 seconds
------------
Execution time for: 0.016284504999999783 seconds
Execution time rem: 0.013322944000000003 seconds
Execution time set: 0.059559609999999985 seconds
------------
Execution time for: 0.07414640800000072 seconds
Execution time rem: 0.013837526000000544 seconds
Execution time set: 0.06460111099999999 seconds
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35062616)