# Find the smallest positive integer not in given list, python

Tags: python

How to find the smallest positve integer that is not in a given list of integers, in the most effective way?

I stumbled across this question in a coding challenge yesterday and thought about this a bit.

Coding challenge: https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/

This was already discussed here:

[Find the smallest positive number not in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176866/find-the-smallest-positive-number-not-in-list/74332660#)

This answer times several solutions, but only for one example input list:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74332660/22656217

Timing the solutions utilizing the for loop and the set method for different lists reveals more about in which cases the set method outperforms the for loop method, namely long lists due to the complexity scaling. I added a third solution here, which removes numbers that were checked already from the list (at least the first instance of them) via the remove() built-in.

```
import timeit

def findSmallestIntNotInList_for(number_list):
    # Infinite while-loop until first number is found
    for i in range(1,len(number_list)+2):
        if i not in number_list:
            return i
        else:
            number_list.remove(i)

def findSmallestIntNotInList_remove(number_list):
    # Infinite while-loop until first number is found
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        if i not in number_list:
            return i
        else:
            number_list.remove(i)

def findSmallestIntNotInList_set(number_list):
    m = range(1, len(number_list)+2)
    return min(set(m)-set(number_list))

lim = 10**(4)
a = list(range(-lim,lim))
b = list(range(-lim,lim))
b.remove(2)
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
c = list(range(-lim,lim))
rng.shuffle(c)
d = list(range(-2*lim,0))
#c = list(rng.integers(-lim,lim, size=len(a)))

lists = [a,b,c,d]
for l in lists:
    
    #t = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList(l))
    t1 = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList_remove(l))
    t2 = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList_for(l))
    t3 = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList_set(l))
    print('Execution time rem:', t1.timeit(10000), 'seconds')
    print('Execution time for:', t2.timeit(10000), 'seconds')
    print('Execution time set:', t3.timeit(10000), 'seconds')
    print('------------')
```

I have several questions about this now, because I submitted both the set method as well as the remove method as solutions, the set method scoring 100% and the remove method only 25%. However, as you can see from the code above the remove method outperforms the set method when timing it.

1. Can you think of a case, where the remove method performs badly?
2. Does the remove method score badly on a different performance metric not related to timing, like cache access or something?
3. Why does the coding challenge assign a lower score to the remove method?
4. Why is the plain for loop faster than the while construct?

Output of the code on my system:

```
Execution time rem: 1.9298538960000002 seconds
Execution time for: 0.5420050019999998 seconds
Execution time set: 5.828596567999999 seconds
------------
Execution time rem: 1.1942714429999999 seconds
Execution time for: 1.1997454950000002 seconds
Execution time set: 13.85635568 seconds
------------
Execution time rem: 3.0267606810000025 seconds
Execution time for: 0.7885398489999993 seconds
Execution time set: 6.929878771999999 seconds
------------
Execution time rem: 1.1609878240000029 seconds
Execution time for: 1.0680834049999959 seconds
Execution time set: 16.141565139 seconds
------------
```

Comment: "1. 2. 3. 4. ": Please focus on one question only.

Comment: is your question about how to write a function that does this efficiently, or is your question about understanding why one of your functions is faster?

Comment: list.remove from the middle of a list is slow on big lists.

Comment: `list.remove` is `O(n)`, so I'd say algorithmically this is not a good approach. For all list-based methods  `i not in number_list` is also `O(n)` you should rather use a set to test membership.

Comment: @julaine thanks for your comment. your suggested method requires to first remove all negative numbers from the list, otherwise min(number_list)-1 will not be a positive integer

Comment: That's why I said find the minimum number that is two or bigger. They don't need to be reomoved. Just ignore them when looping, or use `filter`.

Comment: @julaine i would like to know the most effective way to do this without knowing what kind of list is the input

Comment: What do you assume about the list? Does it always contain numbers? Is it non-empty? Does it contain only integers? Does have to contain a positive integer? Your functions do have assumptions about these kind of things.

Comment: *"i would like to know the most effective way"*: Please ask *one* question only.

Comment: Your tests are broken: your functions *mutate* `l`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your benchmark is broken because the two first function mutate the list and then the list is used for all executions, strongly skewing the result.

Here is the "right" way to do it, whith copies and a better set based algorithm.

```
import timeit
import random


def findSmallestIntNotInList_for(number_list):
    number_list = number_list.copy()
    # Infinite while-loop until first number is found
    for i in range(1, len(number_list) + 2):
        if i not in number_list:
            return i
        else:
            number_list.remove(i)


def findSmallestIntNotInList_remove(number_list):
    number_list = number_list.copy()
    # Infinite while-loop until first number is found
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        if i not in number_list:
            return i
        else:
            number_list.remove(i)
    print("never returned rm")


def findSmallestIntNotInList_set(number_list):
    number_list = number_list.copy()
    m = range(1, len(number_list) + 2)
    return min(set(m) - set(number_list))


def findSmallestIntNotInList_set2(number_list):
    m = set(number_list)

    i = 1
    while True:
        if i not in m:
            return i
        i += 1


lim = 10 ** (4)
a = list(range(-lim, lim))
b = list(range(-lim, lim))
b.remove(2)
c = list(range(-lim, lim))
random.shuffle(c)
d = list(range(-2 * lim, 0))

lists = [a, b, c, d]
for l in lists:
    # t = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList(l))
    t1 = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList_remove(l))
    t2 = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList_for(l))
    t3 = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList_set(l))
    t4 = timeit.Timer(lambda: findSmallestIntNotInList_set2(l))
    print("Execution time rem:", t1.timeit(10), "seconds")
    print("Execution time for:", t2.timeit(10), "seconds")
    print('Execution time set:', t3.timeit(10), 'seconds')
    print("Execution time set2:", t4.timeit(10), "seconds")
    print("------------")
```

Results on my machine:

```
Execution time rem: 9.13231205900047 seconds
Execution time for: 9.487994552999226 seconds
Execution time set: 0.039423326999894925 seconds
Execution time set: 0.008012439999220078 seconds
------------
Execution time rem: 0.002604224999231519 seconds
Execution time for: 0.0019416670002101455 seconds
Execution time set: 0.03944626100019377 seconds
Execution time set: 0.005437456000436214 seconds
------------
Execution time rem: 14.850701602999834 seconds
Execution time for: 15.536581934999049 seconds
Execution time set: 0.038880123998751515 seconds
Execution time set: 0.012132085001212545 seconds
------------
Execution time rem: 0.0013962980010546744 seconds
Execution time for: 0.001398873999278294 seconds
Execution time set: 0.0584400129991991 seconds
Execution time set: 0.005105800000819727 seconds
------------
```

You can see that the set based algorithm is crushing the alternative when for case a and c.
b and d are "best case" for the other two algorithm, so they are slightly  faster.

The first two algorithms are very fast if the number you are looking for is small. However, in average they have a O(N^2) complexity (remove being an O(N) operation on lists).

The set doesn't take advantage of the order, but has always a O(N) complexity (creating the set is O(N) and looking it up is O(1)).
Before, you were doing the work once, and then creating the best case for all other runs.

EDIT:

Maybe an even more python (and slightly faster) algorithm would be:

```
import itertools


def findSmallestIntNotInList_set3(number_list):
    m = set(number_list)

    return next(i for i in itertools.count(1) if i not in m)
```

Comment: `while i in m: i += 1`

Comment: Your discussion of case d doesn't make sense. What numbers do you think that list contains?

Comment: Thank you @WIP, I learned a lot from your answer!

Comment: @KellyBundy ah yes, I got confused at some point. I had a different (but equally bad) algorithm in mind when writing that. I edited my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case it is worth thinking not about how accurate your calculations are in the context of time, but how much they reflect the real complexity of the algorithm. Solving via set, for example, means creating two sets and finding the minimum, which looks like `O(k*n)`. If the solution with `.remove`, which in general promises to be quadratic, has a small constant (which seems to be so), then on small data, a quadratic solution will outperform the solution in linear time, although in theory it should be the other way around. Therefore, I suggest you try to make arrays larger in size and test your solutions on them (assuming that your solutions are correct).

EDIT1. I will correct myself that the solution with sets seems to have a greater constant than 3, since there is also a subtraction of one set from another.

EDIT2. I said about small data - 10 to the fourth power is only 1000, that is very small for accurate measurements. The essence of the algorithmic complexity of algorithms lies in their work on asymptotically large input data sizes (it's also worth mentioning what the input data sizes are, but now it doesn't matter). 1000 elements don't provide asymptotic measure on modern computers.

Comment: the other answer is better because it identifies the problem with the benchmark, but this still contains useful and true information and shouldn't have negative score